# SCSS wont compile - Animation delay

Tags: jquery, css, sass

I am trying to increase the animation delay on all of my i elements incrementally but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. I am evening taking the correct approach or should I be using js? Cheers

http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/ycIpj

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: (#{$i * 0.1})s; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `&` with `li`, see the following code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay:(#{$i*0.1s}); 
  }
}
```

for a markup like this :

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
...
```

"Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'."

Comment: Seems to work apart form I have a space between the animation-delay number and 's' value

Comment: I fixed it by putting the s inside the closed bracket